# Expecting a semi-colon, found '(' at line 25 column 28

Tags: apex

Facing this error in below code, can someone help me out.

```
public class mapdepend {
public string mycity {get;set;}
map<string,List<string>> mybranches= new map<string,List<string>>();
public list<selectoption> city{get;set;}
public list<selectoption> branch{get;set;}
  public mapdepend(){
    list<string> hyd = new list<string>();
    hyd.add('SR Nagar');
    hyd.add('LB Nagar');
    List<string>  bang=  new list<string>();
    bang.add('Ecity');
    bang.add('Matahalli');
    mybranches.put('hyd',hyd);
    mybranches.put('bang',bang);
    set<string> keys= mybranches.keyset();
    city=new list<selectoption>();
    branch=new list<selectoption>();
    List<string> my = new list<string>();
    my.add('None');
     for(string a: keys)
      {
        selectoption op1= new selectoption(a,a);
        city.add(op1);
      }
   public pagereference show() {
       for (mycity : mybranches.keyset())
           { 
           branch.add(mybranches.get(mycity));
           }
       return null;
       }
    }
   }
```

Comment: your constructor is not closed `public mapdepend(){}` ....After ` city.add(op1);
      }` one more close `}`

Comment: Remove the last } and put it after city.add(op1);

Comment: For the people who have downvoted this question, pls let know the OP as to why you downvoted the question.

Answer (score 9):

You can't declare a method in your constructor.

Change:

```
public MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        // do stuff
        public PageReference show() { }
    }
}
```

To:

```
public MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    public PageReference show() { }
}
```